# Unable to Load QT Environment

Tags: qt, qt5, linux-mint

I'm at a complete loss and hoping someone can help.  I'm used to the Visual Studio environment and setup, and QT is new to me.  I'm running Linux Mint (debian 20.04) and installed qt5-default, and qtcreator.  QT creator loaded fine the first time with no issues, however, after closing the application and a system reboot, it refuses to load.  I've been scowering google and stack, I've found some similar issues but none of the solutions I've found so far have worked for me.  Trying to run `qtcreator` from the terminal renders the following output:

```
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by qtcreator)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: no version information available (required by qtcreator)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: no version information available (required by qtcreator)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by qtcreator)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by qtcreator)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libExtensionSystem.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libUtils.so.4)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5)
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5)
qtcreator: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZTI26QAbstractDynamicMetaObject, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API`

qtchooser/default.conf contained
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator
```

From the output, it would appear that there are two conflicting versions, however, being new to QT, I'm not exactly sure how or were I point it to the correct version.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't know what the errors mean, but you could always just go to http://qt.io and download qt creator manually and see if that works for you.

Comment: `sudo apt purge qtcreator` and then locate Qt Maintenance Tool and install the selection what you want https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer I personally find installing Qt Creator as package counter productive.

Comment: That is the problem of MSVC, it makes you depend on you IDE. You eventually don't need QtCreator to make any Qt program: g++/clang and some CMake/qmake is far enough.

Comment: @AlexanderV That did it! I was using the default repository from the application manager to install Qt, but I was never able to get it to load the IDE more than one time after executing the application. Interesting to note, the repository seemed to only have a portion of the application (about 1G download) as opposed to downloading the installer from Qt (about 9Gb download). This seemed to do it. If you’ll post your solution as the answer, I’ll mark it correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should we have a number of lines like:

```
qtcreator: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by qtcreator)
```

Pointing to the root of Linux file system `user` and not to `/home/user` indicates we have installed Qt Creator (not really the latest Qt framework and not even Creator) with `sudo apt install qtcreator` which may come handy as an older IDE but not much else and prone to system errors due to many library soft link redirections etc.

First purge it out of the system:

```
sudo apt purge qtcreator
```

As original poster asked the problem is solved by completely removing package-installed Qt Creator and installing newer Qt complete framework with options with new Qt Creator by using [Qt Maintenance Tool](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer). For which you may want to enable the execution file attribute after it was downloaded:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run
~/Downloads/qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run
```

P.S. Mind the above installs Qt Creator and the framework for the user but of course with `sudo` and pointing to the right location we could install Qt for the entire system as root somehow yet it is discouraged: https://forum.qt.io/topic/31366/install-qt-qt-creator-as-root Then why would `sudo apt install qtcreator` still be widely spread option? If so allowing the other user to access your files with some soft-link exercise will do.